# Particles/fluid attaches or fills the volume of an object

Tags: particles, fluid-simulation, force-fields

Holla,

Right, so I'm curious on how to achieve a certain effect via two different approaches.

What I'm sort of trying to achieve: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KFYFh8w4758

Case 1: I'm looking for a method for particles to exit the emitter, follow a path until near the target object, and afterwards be attracted and stick to the surface of the object, or fill the volume.

Case 2: Same thing, but closer to the Daredevil intro, where the particles fill the exterior of the shape from bottom up.

I couldn't find anything remotely close online, so any help would be hugely appreciated!